# Kotlin MenuHost Provider not Working onMenuItemSelected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The Menu Host will not trigger with a MenuItem.itemId

I have attemped multiple diffent methods but all to lead nothing working.

The Menu that I have chosen to display shows up but the actions do not work

The object: MenuProvider

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()


  menuHost.addMenuProvider(object :MenuProvider{

  override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {

      menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.maps_toggle,menu)
                }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {

                return when(menuItem.itemId){
                    R.id.toggle_group->{
                        Log.d("FavPlaceOverserMaps1", "it.toString()")
                        if (isChecked){
                            favPlacesViewModel.readAllLocations.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                                Log.d("FavPlaceOverserMaps", it.toString())
                            })
                        }
                        true
                    }
                    else->{
                        false
                    }
                }
            }


        },viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
}
```

I have a switch in the menu and the menu does not trigger when toggled

```
if(menuItem.isChecked == true){
menuItem.isCheck = isChecked
//do something 
}
```

I am unsure if something is wrong as I have moved off the deprecated  way of doing a menu handler

Activity Import

```
import androidx.core.view.MenuHost
import androidx.core.view.MenuProvider
```

Dependency,

most dependency are here others include Firebase and Google

```
dependencies {
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.1"
   implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.1"

   kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10"

   //implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
   implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1"

   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'

   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-alpha03'


   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
}
```

Comment: What is the `dependencies` section of your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @ianhanniballake A Photo of **Module**  or **Project** **Dependencies** ?

Comment: You can edit your question to add the dependencies section (it would be the one with things like appcompat or fragment)

Comment: @ianhanniballake dependencies are up,  The MenuProvider uses the **'core:core-ktx:1.8.0'**